# Set group's offsets to latest with Python's confluent-kafka (one-time admin action)

Tags: python, confluent-kafka-python

Say that I have a topic `my-topic` and a group `my-group`, and that my clients use the `confluent-kafka` Python package. Consumers are configured with `"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"` to ensure that all messages are processed at least once. Now say I accidentally add 10,000 malformed messages to `my-topic` during early development. As a one-time administrative action, I want to seek `my-group`'s offsets to the end of each partition so that I never see those messages again. I don't care if extra messages slip into the topic in the mean time, and I end up skipping more messages than necessary. I also don't care about whether other groups see those malformed messages. Is this kind of "fast-forwarding" possible to do at the group level, maybe with `AdminClient`? Or am I stuck with shutting down the existing consumers, writing a script to create a consumer in the `my-group` group, consuming messages and commiting offsets until those messages are gone, closing that consumer, and rebooting my real consuming process?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this example of setting the offset directly on the partitions: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/145#issuecomment-284843254

For example:

```py
import confluent_kafka

NEW_OFFSET = 666

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = confluent_kafka.Consumer({
        "bootstrap.servers": "eden:9092", 
        "group.id":"my-group"
    })

    def my_assign (consumer, partitions):
        for p in partitions:
            p.offset = NEW_OFFSET
        print('assign', partitions)
        consumer.assign(partitions)

    c.subscribe(["my-topic"], on_assign=my_assign)

    while True:
        m = c.poll(1)
        if m is None:
            continue

        if m.error() is None:
            print('Received message', m)


    c.close()
```

Comment: Won't this change the offset as it polls? Is there a way to do this as a prep action for when the consumers turn on at a later time?